# Cannot add user's input data to database PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I got this error in my php code:

> Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\WEBDEV\save.php on line 144 Form submitted
>   failed!

Here's my code:

```
    <?php
            $connect = mysql_connect ("localhost", "root");
            $db = mysql_select_db ($connect, "signup");

            $idnum = $_POST ['idnum'];
            $fname = $_POST ['fname'];
            $lname = $_POST ['lname'];
            $course = $_POST ['course'];
            $yrlvl = $_POST ['yrlvl'];
            $pass = $_POST ['pass'];

            $Query = mysql_query ("insert into admin (idnum, fname, lname, course, yrlvl, pass) 
                                values ('$idnum', '$fname', '$lname', '$course', '$yrlvl', '$pass')", $connect);
            if ($Query)
            {
                print "Form submitted successfully! <br>";`e`enter code here`nter code here`
            }

            else
            {
                print "Form submitted failed! <br>";
            }   
        ?>
```

Comment: Change positions of the parameters. change `mysql_select_db ($connect, "signup");` to `mysql_select_db ( "signup",$connect);`

Comment: Please stop using PHP's deprecated mysql_ API. See about mysqli_/PDO and bound queries

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to use "**your_db_name**" in front of database link identifier.
Assuming `"signup"` is your database name:

```
 $db = mysql_select_db ("signup", $connect);
```

Warning:
`mysql_connect()` and `mysql_select_db()` is deprecated and removed from php 7.0. Use `mysqli_connect()` instead. Example:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
```

similarly, the mysql_select_db() can be implemented as:

```
mysqli_select_db($link, "signup");
```

Comment: Just a quick question... Why would you need to select a database if you already specified the database that you would like to use in the connection? I am not really sure if I would do that personally, but can you please explain?

Comment: actually I was trying to explain two different function's implement.  Thanks for the comment. I will update my answer.

Comment: I just don't think we should be advocating the use of an insecure and long since deprecated API